# How to 3D Volume Render using VTK in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, vtk, dicom, volume-rendering

I'm new in the field of C#, using it to render DICOM images via VTK TKit. I've already installed vtk in Visual Studio, and I'm trying to create a 3D Volume Rendering of DICOM image. I suppose that I've got to study how to implement the dll files of the vtk TKit, in order to proceed with the 3D Volume Rendering creation. So, the question is: What to start with?

Comment: did you find it out please ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [ActiViz.NET](http://www.kitware.com/opensource/avdownload.php), to get the C# binding (Keep in mind that VTK is C++). You may then compile GDCM + C# binding to get a better DICOM reader than the default provided by VTK.

On debian-like system, simply do:

```
sudo apt-get install libvtkgdcm-cil
```

On windows, follows the [build instructions](http://gdcm.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Configuring_and_Building_With_VS_.NET_2008_%28Include_C_sharp_wrapping%29)